# how can I create UI like on picture?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I am developing news flutter app, how can I create UI like in the picture below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwDTl.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `TabBar` widget to get this look.

check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x2Ssf5OxQ4) video here

upvote if it helps, and let me know if further queries arise.

Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific?
on which design you need help.

I had a look at the attached image It has the below designs

1. Tab bar with gradients bar
2. Search button placed over the tab bar
3. Listview with custom card
4. custom card having image and content side by side.

Comment: 1. Tab bar with gradients bar. I want to create it